# Is $z = x^2y^3(1-x-y)$ convex or concave?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

Is there some kind of trick to defining the domain of the concavity/convexity (if it exists)? I have no idea how to work with the resultant hessian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to see that we can not say that $$\frac{\partial^2(x^2y^3(1-x-y))}{\partial x^2}\geq0$$ for all reals $x$ and $y$ and we can not say that 
$$\frac{\partial^2(x^2y^3(1-x-y))}{\partial x^2}\leq0$$ for all reals $x$ and $y$.

What does follow from this?

Comment: I'm trying to specify specific intervals in the domain, however, where concavity /convexity may or may not be achieved. //Oh wait! 0<x<y for the top one, and y<x<0 for the second one is the only time the inequality holds!

Comment: Just calculate three second partial derivatives, the hessian and write the system. It does not give something interesting.

Comment: what am i doing with my life

Comment: @elbarto NO! The Math it's the most beautiful  thing in our life.